# Slide to limit content of SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, slidingdrawer

Hi I am doing a sliding drawer, following the tutorial here: http://android-pro.blogspot.sg/2010/09/using-android-slidingdrawer.html

However, the sliding drawer either open or closes fully. Is there any way so that the user can slide to limit the height of content? For example to slide open half of the sliding drawer to show half of the content, or slide a third to see a third of the content.

Comment: post your code for sliding drawer

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a custom 'SlidingDrawer' so that its top offset does not default to the max height.

It is [already implemented here](http://chrisharrington1.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/android-modifying-the-slidingdrawer-widget-to-use-a-max-height/)